# @SecurityTestExecutionListeners does not configure SecurityContext

Tags: spring-security

I want to test a class that gets the authenticated user from the Security Context. According to the [Spring-Security-Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7.2/servlet/test/method.html), it's enough to annotate the test with `@SecurityTestExecutionListeners` to set up a SecurityContext, and then provide a user with @WithMockUser, which should then be available as an Authentication object.

So this test should pass, shouldn't it?

```
@SecurityTestExecutionListeners
class SecurityServiceTest {

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "foo")
    void should_find_user() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        assertThat(authentication).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

But the test fails. Did I miss something, or is this a bug?

BTW: With `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@SecurityTestExecutionListeners` the test runs successfully.

Comment: read the docs you linked especially the last part in the `note` section https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/method.html#test-method-setup, you need `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`

Comment: Uh, yes, that did the trick. Thank you so much!